# How to open source code and modify gui of slic3r software?

Tags: git

I have installed slic3r for my MAC, using this link of git https://github.com/alexrj/Slic3r/wiki/Running-Slic3r-from-git-on-OS-X. 
This program ran properly.
But now I want to open the source code of the software and modify it. If you know how to do that, please tell me.

I'm looking for advice on how to proceed with what I would like to do.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, clarify your question whether you need help on how to program and contribute to the project in general or if you have a specific problem you need help with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to modify the GUI (graphical user interface) of Slic3r software which is an open source software. As I know, its GUI is coded in Perl Language. I used this link to run Slic3r. https://github.com/alexrj/Slic3r/wiki/Running-Slic3r-from-git-on-OS-X
But I don't know how to open Slic3r Project and make any changes of it.

Answer (score 0):

To open the soruce code you first need to download it. You can do so by going to the projects github page https://github.com/alexrj/Slic3r

Then click "Clone or download" and either clone the project using git or download a zip file containing the entire project.